# How to Add Metadata to Haystack Documents Using Pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, metadata, haystack

I'm modifying the Haystack [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack-tutorials/blob/main/tutorials/01_Basic_QA_Pipeline.ipynb) to make a basic extractive QA system. Everything works great, but now I want to link each answer back to its original .txt file.

When printing the predicted answers with pprint, each answer has an attribute `document_ids` that looks like this: `'document_ids': ['c4711696aa2c81c609932143da711ea3']`. This helps link back to the right `Document` object from the `DocumentStore`, and the `Document` objects have a 'meta' attribute that looks like the right place to store the original file name.

How can I edit this notebook to save the file name with each `Document` in the `DocumentStore`?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained, meaning all necessary details need to be included in the post.

Comment: If you want a quick feedback, you can reach the Deepset team and the Haystack community through Github discussions (https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions) or Discord (https://haystack.deepset.ai/community)